# TOC numbering of sections not incrementing correctly in lyx

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, lyx

I've recently discovered Lyx and am thoroughly impressed by what it can do. I'm writing my thesis in Lyx (using the article class) and would like the table of contents to look like this:

## Part I Methods

### 1.1 Method A

### 1.2 Method B

### 1.3 Method C

etc...
However, I get something rather different:

Part I Methods

1 Method A

2 Method B

etc...

I had a similar problem for my results section, but managed to solve it by adding ERT after applying the section label to the results heading:

```
\setcounter{section}{0}
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work when trying the same for the methods section. How can I get the Lyx output (using PDFlatex) to number the sections correctly?

Comment: Thanks!! You certainly pointed me in the right direction. Considering that the "Part" was labelled in Roman numerals, your command gave me sections labelled: III.1, III.2, etc... I then tried \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}} which then gave me the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add this line in your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}}
```

and the sections will be numbered as you want them to be.